# Recurrence Relation with factorial term

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I was solving some practice problems on recurrence relation for my upcoming exam and came across the following question.

Solve the recurrence relation T(n) = (n-1) T(n-1) + (n+1)! with the initial condition T(1) = 1.

I tried several techniques to solve it but it was of no use. Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: This one is quite tricky. WolframAlpha outputs $\frac13(n+2)! - (n-1)!$ as the solution, but I'm not sure how to derive that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do is to consider the Sequence $$U(n)=\frac{T(n)}{(n-1)!}$$
Hence you can show
$$
U(n+1)=U(n)+(n+1)(n+2)
$$
You can then, sum this relation to find $U(n)$ (telescopic sums)

Comment: This surely helps. Thanks for your suggestion.